# Why do annuity payments end earlier in Excel?

Tags: excel, annuity

I am trying to calculate load payments with `PMT` function. I set total amout, rate per year, divided rate by `12`, multiplied number of years by `12` and got:

[image]

Expected duration is 5 years, which should end at 06/01/2022 (we have `DD.MM.YYYY` format).

In each payment I subtracted payment from remaining sum

[image]

and sheet shows that payments will end in `2021` not in `2022`.

Why?

Comment: You are subtracting the whole payment from the amount when a portion of each payment is to pay for the interest.  You need to figure out how much of each payment is interest and how much goes to the balance and it is the second part that needs to be subtracted from the balance.

Comment: @ScottCraner is there `Excel` function for this?

Comment: `=D7 * (E1/12)` will get the amount in interest.  Then subtract that from the PMT to get the amount that goes to the balance.

Comment: @ScottCraner this is constant, while in annuity it should change

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are subtracting the whole payment from the amount when a portion of each payment is to pay for the interest.

You need to figure out how much of each payment is interest and how much goes to the balance and it is the second part that needs to be subtracted from the balance.

To figure how much is Interest:

```
=-D7*($E$1/12)
```

Then to find how much goes tot the balance we simply subtract the interest from the payment:

```
=E7-F7
```

Then you add that to the balance and copy down.

[image]